# Passing multiple parameters with laravel routes but keep the url "clean" (without showing them)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, parameters, routes

I'm working on an application using php framework Laravel.

I've encountered a problem since I need to open a modification form with two parameters. I pass them in my url like so:

```
<tr class="beBlack" onclick="document.location = '/showGriefs/{{$data->No_Grief}}/{{$data->No_Employe}}'">
```

(I know that it is sketchy to create a link within a table but I need the url to change according to which row is clicked/selected)

and I receive them in the following route:

```
Route::any('/showGriefs/{No_Grief}/{No_Employe}', 'GriefController@showGrief')->name('showGriefs');
```

My problem is that I don't want my url to change, because, with these url changes, my application can't find the files (CSS, JS and Plugins). And since laravel is using the public directory to store all those files, it's destroying my page. The only errors I get are some missing files error.

I've searched the internet a lot but didn't found anything, I hope you'll all be able to help me. Thanks.

Comment: *"but i need the url to change"* followed by *"i don't want my url to change"* is very conflicting... Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Probably you need to fix how your application find CSS, JS and Plugins

Comment: I mean that i want my url to change to /showGriefs and not to /showGriefs/param1/param2 @TimLewis

Comment: I'm using a "masterpage" so i find my files in my layout so the content within can use these files @FelippeDuarte

Comment: To get params from the URL like that you need to navigate to `/route/{param}/{param2}`, so that's not possible. Consider using a `GET` request with queryString (`/route?param=...`) or a `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 solutions to fix your problem. No need to change route URLs. Just fix asset problem.

## 1. Use / before asset url

If you use `/` before url, browser will try to look at resource on the root dir.

For example: if you need `http://example.com/assets/img.png` then use `/assets/img.png`. Changing URLs will not affect the asset URLs that starts with `/` character.

## 2. Use url helpers for asset URLs

`asset('assets/img.png')` will change asset url from `assets/img.png` to `http://example.com/assets/img.png`